# Python - Plotting Error Bar Chart with Uneven Errors (High and Low)

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I am new on Stack Overflow so apologize if this is a duplicate question or is vague - I am also new at Python and coding in general.

I am wanting to create an error bar graph that has unequal "error limits" on high versus low.

I will be plotting average temperature for a month, with the upper error needing to be the highest temperature of the month and the lower error needing to be the lowest temperature of the month.

I understand how to use an error bar with the errors being equal, but do not understand how to make them unequal.

A picture has been added for reference. A shortened example of the lists I will be using to graph are:

```
temps_avg = [46, 49, 58, 69, 73, 79, 84]
temps_high = [78, 80, 82, 88, 88, 93, 101]
temps_low = [21, 29, 25, 48, 54, 62, 70]
```

Bar Chart I'd Like to Duplicate but without Even Error Bars

[image: Bar Chart I'd Like to Duplicate but without Even Error Bars]

Answer (score 5):

You can place the low and high error limits inside a tuple in the yerr arg of matplotlib's bar plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], temps_avg, yerr = (temps_low,temps_high))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me you can do either of

1. Draw upper and lower limits separately using `lolims`, `uplims` arguments  ([see here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html))
2. Pass the `y` argument to `errorbar` so that upper and lower errors are equal, i.e. in your case `y = (temps_high+temps_low)/2`, this way using temp_avg only to plot line but not the errors.