# Plot error bar around a point with uneven upper and lower limits

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, errorbar

I've found several similar questions, for example: [Python - Plotting Error Bar Chart with Uneven Errors (High and Low)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138250/python-plotting-error-bar-chart-with-uneven-errors-high-and-low)

But when I was trying with my data, I got some weird results. I have an original dataframe `dotvalue`:

```
ticker  AAPL    AMD BIDU    GOOGL   IXIC    MSFT    NDXT    NVDA    NXPI    QCOM    SWKS    TXN
5   0.222649    3.512100e-02    0.043558    0.153921    0.374783    0.201710    0.377886    0.159817    0.206961    0.151937    0.132801    0.226767
10  0.203363    3.398862e-02    0.113287    0.173990    0.393209    0.236895    0.421558    0.205209    0.326829    0.128487    0.174043    0.312648
...
145 0.089661    4.591069e-05    0.136814    0.017958    0.030406    0.000834    0.083278    0.162984    0.081382    0.081221    0.047221    0.057464
150 0.143404    2.403103e-02    0.076241    0.113305    0.061792    0.014000    0.096749    0.060709    0.170400    0.341342    0.049486    0.059982
```

and the dot plot is like below:
[image]

And for each value on x-axis, I have a series called `avg=dotvalue.mean(axis=1)` which looks like:

```
5      0.190659
10     0.226959
...
145    0.065772
150    0.100953
```

And if I add the `avg` to the plot, it looks like below:
[image]

Then I calculate the confidence interval as:

```
ci_u = dotvalue.quantile(q=0.975, axis=1) # upper limit
ci_l = dotvalue.quantile(q=0.025, axis=1) # lower limit
```

and `ci_u` is like:

```
5      0.377033
10     0.413762
...
145    0.155787
150    0.294333
```

`ci_l` is like:

```
5      0.037441
10     0.055796
...
145    0.000263
150    0.016758
```

For each x value, I want the `ci_u` as upper bound of the error bar around the `avg`, and `ci_l` as the lower bound.

I tried `avg.plot(yerr = (ci_l, ci_u), ls = '-', marker = 'o', figsize = (10,5), label = "average")` which gives me:
[image]

which is clearly wrong, since for example, when x=5, the upper bound should be 0.377033 and lower bound should be 0.037441, while the error bar on the plot for x=5 is something like (0.15, 0.57).

Any help on why this happens and how I should correct it?

Comment: I think the `yerr` are just the errors only, so you need to substract `ci_u` by the mean.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, thank you!